# Settings Root View Controller different if app opens via push notification?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I have a default launch for my app, however in some instances I want the app to open via a push notification which delivers a payload identifying a page to load.

The issue i have is the payload logic is handled in didRecieve response for push notifications, and i also handle the apps launch in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

How can i stop the two conflicting as currently it seems to crash the app.

Essentially I want to change the root on launch based on the payload from the notification.

Currently I have:

```
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
    // map
    let conferenceID = userInfo["cid"] as! String
    self.pushNotifiedEventID = conferenceID
    self.defaultEvent = conferenceID
    if let p = userInfo["p"] as? [String : String] {
        let pageID = p["id"]!
        let title = p["title"]!
        let type = p["type"]!
    }
    completionHandler()
    let hostViewController = HostViewController()
    self.window?.rootViewController = hostViewController
}
```

and also:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        center.delegate = self
        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.badge, .alert , .sound]) { (granted, error) in
            if granted {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                })
            }
        }
    } else {
        let type: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.alert, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
        let setting = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: type, categories: nil)
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(setting)
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
    // root VC init + push
    window = UIWindow()
    let loginViewController = LoginViewController.init(loginView: LoginView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds))
    self.navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginViewController)
    window?.rootViewController = navigationController
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your AppDelegate class, create a method:

```
func configureRootView(isComingFromNotification: Bool) {
  if isComingFromNotification {
    self.window?.rootViewController = HostViewController()
  }
  else {
    let loginViewController = LoginViewController.init(loginView: LoginView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds))
    self.navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: loginViewController)
    window?.rootViewController = navigationController
  }
}
```

And you call this method from both your `func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)` and `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool` methods.

Comment: thanks i get the logic but im setill getting a crash, any idea how i can diagnose a crash when i cant run plugged into the debugger as i have to terminate the app to test the notification